# A RenderFlex overflowed by 40 pixels on the bottom. Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Card(
      child: ListTile(
         title: new Text(prod_name),
         leading: Image.asset(prod_img, width: 50.0, height: 50.0,),
         subtitle: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               new Row(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                     child: new Text("ice-cream: "),
                   ),
                   Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                     child: new Text(prod_ice_cream, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
                   ),
               ),
               new Container(
                 alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                 child: new Text("\Rs${prod_price}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
             ),
             trailing: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                   new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), onPressed: (){}),
                   new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down), onPressed: (){})
               ],
             ),
    ),
);
```

I am getting "A RenderFlex overflowed by 40 pixels on the bottom" after adding those two icons
I have tried [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57253706/12536525) solution gave but after that I am getting  "A RenderFlex overflowed by 21 pixels on the bottom". Here are some screenshots [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vW7rR.png) [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NayFY.png) [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44x80.png). Here is my full code [code](https://codeshare.io/GAxNZp)

Comment: Your code cant even compiled.

Comment: Please do post screenshot

Comment: added some screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Text widget is throwing overflow error then just set set the overflow property to a Text widget.

Example:

```
Flexible(
  child: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
    child: new Text(
      'Your Text Value Here',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,

    ),
  ),
),
```

Here is the solution using `Container` instead of `ListTile`:

```
class Single_cart_prod extends StatelessWidget {
  final prod_name;
  final prod_img;
  final prod_price;
  final prod_ice_cream;
  final prod_sugar;

  Single_cart_prod(
      {this.prod_name,
      this.prod_img,
      this.prod_price,
      this.prod_ice_cream,
      this.prod_sugar});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 80,
        child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Image.asset(prod_img, width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      prod_name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Rs:" + prod_price.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black38),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Ice Cream",
                    ),
                    Text(
                      prod_ice_cream,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Sugar",
                    ),
                    Text(
                      prod_sugar,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up), onPressed: () {})),
                    Expanded(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                            onPressed: () {}))
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: On line number 68 you are passing a string to a Text widget which is relatively big for the space available and that why you are getting this error. Wrap that text field in Flexible and Container with Overflow property like given above. This will get rid of Overflow error but the text of that Text widget will be trimmed and will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

check out this example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Cartproduct());

class Cartproduct extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartproductState createState() => _CartproductState();
}

class _CartproductState extends State<Cartproduct> {
  var cart_list = [
    {
      "name": "Avocado",
      "img": "images/avocado.jpg",
      "price": 180,
      "ice-cream": "2 scoops",
      "sugar": "3 cube"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mango",
      "img": "images/mango.jpg",
      "price": 180,
      "ice-cream": "1 scoops",
      "sugar": "2 cube"
    },
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: new ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return new Single_cart_prod(
              prod_name: cart_list[index]['name'],
              prod_img: cart_list[index]['img'],
              prod_price: cart_list[index]['price'],
              prod_ice_cream: cart_list[index]['ice-cream'],
              prod_sugar: cart_list[index]['sugar'],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Single_cart_prod extends StatelessWidget {
  final prod_name;
  final prod_img;
  final prod_price;
  final prod_ice_cream;
  final prod_sugar;

  Single_cart_prod(
      {this.prod_name,
      this.prod_img,
      this.prod_price,
      this.prod_ice_cream,
      this.prod_sugar});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: new Text(prod_name),
        leading: Image.asset(
          prod_img,
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
        ),
        subtitle: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text("Ice-cream: "),
                    new Text(
                      prod_ice_cream,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(" Sugar: "),
                    new Text(
                      prod_sugar,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: new Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: new Text(
                          "\Rs${prod_price}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {}, child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up)),
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {}, child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score -1):

use **SingleChildScrollView** widget like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: your_main_Widget()
)
```